# undefined reference to `getline' in c

Tags: c, reference, undefined, getline, mingw32

I am learning to use getline in C programming and tried the codes from http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int atgc, char *argv[])
{
    int bytes_read = 1;
    int nbytes = 10;
    char *my_string;

    my_string = (char *)malloc(nbytes+1);

    puts("Please enter a line of text");

    bytes_read = getline(&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

    if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
        puts ("ERROR!");
    }
    else
    {
        puts ("You typed:");
        puts (my_string);
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

However, the problem is that the compiler keeps returning errors of this: **undefined reference to 'getline'**.
Could you please tell me what the problem is? Thank you!

I am using Win7 64bit + Eclipse Indigo + MinGW

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-std=gnu90`?

Comment: This is not a good C tutorial, or rather not a C tutorial at all. I would not recommend using it as your only or main source of information about C.

Answer (score 21):

The other answers have covered most of this, but there are several problems. First, [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) is not in the C standard library, but is a POSIX 2008 extension. Normally, it will be available with a POSIX-compatible compiler, as the macros _POSIX_C_SOURCE will be defined with the appropriate values. You possibly have an older compiler from before `getline()` was standardized, in which case this is a GNU extension, and you must `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <stdio.h>` to enable it, and must be using a GNU-compatible compiler, such as gcc.

Additionally, `nbytes` should have type `size_t`, not `int`. On my system, at least, these are of different size, with `size_t` being longer, and using an `int*` instead of a `size_t*` can have grave consequences (and also doesn't compile with default gcc settings). See the getline manual page (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) for details.

With that change made, your program compiles and runs fine on my system.

Comment: Does it get standardized now? after 9 years.

Comment: @VimNing Nope. still not in the standard lib, but at least they're on the TR block now. Brick by brick... (and a whole lot of sitting on asses doing nada).

Comment: @NeoZoom.lua The time it takes for C to standardize things is generally speaking measured in decades.

Answer (score 9):

I am also using MinGW. I checked MinGW headers and `getline()` does not appear in any C header, it appears only in C++ headers. This means the C function `getline()` does not exist in MinGW.

Answer (score 8):

`getline` isn't a standard function, you need to set a feature test macro to use it, according to my man page,

```
_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700
```

for glibc 2.10 or later,

```
_GNU_SOURCE
```

before that.

Answer (score 2):

`getline()` is not in the C standard library. However, you may still use it with compiler flag `-std=gnu99`. This flag, telling the compiler to use the GNU dialect of ISO C99, is supported by both `gcc` and `clang`.

```bash
gcc main.c -std=gnu99
```

See gcc [flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

The manual (obtained by `man getline` in terminal) also says that

```
       getline(), getdelim():
           Since glibc 2.10:
               _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L
           Before glibc 2.10:
               _GNU_SOURCE
```

So you may add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` or `#define _GUN_SOURCE` to your file to expose the declaration.

If you fancy, here is a basic implementation of `getline()`

```c
ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n,
        FILE *restrict stream) {

    register char c;
    register char *cs = NULL;
    register int length = 0;
    while ((c = getc(stream)) != EOF) {
        cs = (char *)realloc(cs, ++length + 1);
        if ((*(cs + length - 1) = c) == '\n') {
            *(cs + length) = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    // return the allocated memory if lineptr is null
    if ((*lineptr) == NULL) {
        *lineptr = cs;
    } 
    else {
        // check if enough memory is allocated 
        if ((length + 1) < *n) {
            *lineptr = (char *)realloc(*lineptr, length + 1);
        }
        memcpy(*lineptr, cs, length);
        free(cs);
    }
    return (ssize_t)(*n = strlen(*lineptr));
}
```