# Where/how to get the "getline" function if it is missing from stdio.h?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, getline

I'm writing a program in C using Code::Blocks 13.12 on Windows 8 (the C compiler is mingw32-gcc). I would like to use the "getline" function but it seems to be missing from the stdio.h. Is there any way to get it except for writing own implementation?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112784/undefined-reference-to-getline-in-c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`getline` is a POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html), and Windows isn't POSIX, so it doesn't have some POSIX C functions available.

You'll need to roll your own. Or use one that [has already been written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735472/256138).

Comment: Or use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) which is part of the C stdlib?

Comment: @Mr.Llama [If you're careful, sure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16323215/256138)...

Comment: @rubenvb Looked over your [has already been written](http://stackoverflow.com/a/735472/256138).  Not a bad implementation, but needs a few corner case improvements.

Comment: @chux it's not mine, but feel free to tell the author of that code (who seems to need a reason why no one writes their own code anymore). It'd be a great reality check for him/her.

Comment: @rubenvb  The author says: "15 minutes, and I haven't written C in 10 years."  In addition, the author acknowledged the edge cases, but couldn't be bothered to do yet more homework. Also the author was wondering if anyone "writes code anymore," which is not the same as "needing a reason..."  It's a valid question, as most code these days is garbage and bloated.  If people wrote their own code at this super basic level, the state of the web would be at least an order of magnitude better than it is now.  And we wouldn't have to wade through snide remarks like the "great reality check" one.

Answer (score 5):

`getline` is not a standard C library function.  Some implementations (such as `gcc`) provide it as an extension.

If you're compiling with gcc, you'll need to define the feature macro `_GNU_SOURCE` in order to make it available for your code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
...
getline (...);
```

**EDIT**

Hopefully since mingw is a GNU compiler, this should be available for you on windows.

Comment: @rubenvb: or that, yes.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I couldn't even find getline in stdio.h source file.

Comment: gcc does not provide functions like getline(). These functions come from your platform's libc. MinGW uses Microsoft's libc (msvcrt.dll) with MinGW's headers.