# Program crashing at realloc

Tags: c, file, line, realloc

### Problem

I am currently writing a small (and bad) grep-like program for Windows. In it I want to read files line by line and print out the ones which contain a key. For this to work I need a function which reads each line of a file. Since I am not on Linux I cannot use the `getline` function and have to implement it myself.

I have found an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29577105/7057528) where such a function is implemented. I tried it out and it works fine for 'normal' text files. But the program crashes if I try to read a file with a line length of 13 000 characters.

### MCVE

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * getline(FILE *f)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t len  = 0;
    size_t last = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;

    do {
        size += BUFSIZ; /* BUFSIZ is defined as "the optimal read size for this platform" */
        buf = realloc(buf, size); /* realloc(NULL,n) is the same as malloc(n) */            
        /* Actually do the read. Note that fgets puts a terminal '\0' on the
           end of the string, so we make sure we overwrite this */
        if (buf == NULL) return NULL;
        fgets(buf + last, size, f);
        len = strlen(buf);
        last = len - 1;
    } while (!feof(f) && buf[last] != '\n');
    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    while (!feof(file))
    {
        char *line = getline(file);
        if (line != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", line);
            free(line);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the [file](https://pastebin.com/FYebHBEG) I am using. It contains three short lines which get read just fine and a long one from one of my Qt projects. When reading this line the `getline` function reallocates 2 times to a size of 1024 and crashes at the 3rd time. I've put `printf` around the `realloc` to make sure it crashes there and it definitely does.

### Question

Could anyone explain me why my program is crashing like that? I just spend hours with this and don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You *add* `size + BUFSIZ` and allocate that, but then you *read* that same – increased! – `size`. In essence, you are reading more and more characters than you allocated in each turn. If you read only `BUFSIZE` then this should work.

Comment: You don't check if `fgets()` fails...

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you! I could swear I've already tried this because it didn't make much sense to me either. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. Cheers.

Comment: regarding: `buf = realloc(buf, size);`  when calling `realloc()`, always save the returned value into a 'temp' variable, check that 'temp' variable and only if not NULL then copy to the target variable.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the pointer to the allocated memory is lost, resulting in a memory leak is the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this fragment

```
    size += BUFSIZ;
    buf = realloc(buf, size);
    if (buf == NULL) return NULL;
    fgets(buf + last, size, f);
```

you *add* `size + BUFSIZ` and allocate that, but then you read that same – increased! – `size`. In essence, you are reading more and more characters than you allocated in each turn. The first time around, `size = BUFSIZ` and you read exactly `size`/`BUFSIZ` characters. If the line is longer than this (the last character is not `\n`), you increase the size of the memory (`size += BUFSIZ`) but you *also* read its (new) *total* size again – and you've already processes that last number of `size` bytes.

The allocated memory grows with `BUFSIZE` per loop, but the amount of bytes to read *increases* with `BUFSIZE` – after one loop, it's `BUFSIZE`, after two loops `2*BUFSIZE`, and so on, until something important gets overwritten and the program is terminated.

If you read only chunks of the exact size of `BUFSIZE` then this should work.

Note that your code expects the last line to end with an `\n`, which may not always be true. You can catch this with an additional test:

```
if (!fgets(buf + last, size, f))
    break;
```

so your code won't be trying to read past the end of the input file.