# undefined reference to getdelim() error (Windows) (C Language)

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to work with `getdelim()` function which apperantly is the preferred method with `getline()` over `fgets()`. However, when I try to run the code below, I get **undefined reference to getdelim()** error.

I don't think it has anything to do with the code but rather the gcc version that I am using. So to the cmd I typed `gcc -v` and apperantly I have `gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

I am not sure how old it is or if that's the problem. If so, what version of the gcc should I use and can I solve this with adding some fancy macros?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    char *string;

    printf ("Please enter a string: ");

    string = (char*)malloc(size);

    getdelim (&string, &size, '-', stdin);

    printf( "%s\n", string );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the only message you get from your compiler? What compiler options are you using?

Comment: `getdelim()` is not a standard C function, it's a GNU extension. You have to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` *before* including `stdio.h`. If that doesn't work either, your library does not have the function.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yeah it didn't work. Can I maually add the function or can I upgrade the library?

Comment: No you can't manually add it. Yon can try with another version or a different C library although that's a different problem.

Comment: @KamilCuk
make all 
'Building target: project'
'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'
gcc  -o "project"  ./src/tryingGetDelim.o   
./src/tryingGetDelim.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\project\Debug/../src/tryingGetDelim.c:13: undefined reference to `getdelim'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:32: project] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

01:36:15 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 211ms)

I am not sure what compiler options I use, I didn't modified them so probably eclipse default optns

Comment: Sorry, but mingw gcc just does not support GNU getdelim() functions. `what version of the gcc` it's not a version of gcc, rather version of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations) you use. mingw gcc uses msvcrt, which just does not implement `getdelim()`. You can install cygwin, which I think uses newlib, which implements [getdelim](https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdio/getdelim.c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where/how to get the "getline" function if it is missing from stdio.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381903/where-how-to-get-the-getline-function-if-it-is-missing-from-stdio-h)

Comment: No, at that link they say add the macro that Marco Bonelli mentioned, which does not work. I really don't want to setup another compiler and link it :/ Can I upgrade C Standart Library? Sorry If I'm missing stuff here, but does what you say mean that I cannot use it with minGW? I didn't quite understand.