# undefined reference to `getline' in c #define _GNU_SOURCE

Tags: c, windows-7, getline, stdio

i was tring to make a reader in C because i am new in this lenguage in win 7, i use all kind of library but nothing work. This is what i did:

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("tableros.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

but this code give me the same error `undefined reference to getline in c`, i really don t know what error could be, so i try with other library that i find [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) here is the other try, is the same code but with `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700` :

```
#include "linkedlist.h"
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 700 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("tableros.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

so i really don t know what could be, here i gonna put a screenshot of my editor in the case that the problem could be a compiler or another thing that i didn t see :( :
[image]
 here are the errors that C give me with more detail:

```
C:\Users\RAULDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cctm12ki.o tablero.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `getline'
C:\Users\Raul del Rio\Desktop\archivos c sist oper\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you try like in the example code here https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline ?

Comment: i tried now and don t work :(

Comment: `getline()` is a POSIX function that might not be present on whatever Windows libc your program is linking against.

Comment: so what do you propose :(?, because i need some place to test my codes

Comment: this question already has an answer [getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381903/where-how-to-get-the-getline-function-if-it-is-missing-from-stdio-h)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where/how to get the "getline" function if it is missing from stdio.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381903/where-how-to-get-the-getline-function-if-it-is-missing-from-stdio-h)

Comment: You can also use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), if you want port applications which uses POSIX functions.