# How to take first row from this list of text?

Tags: c, function, eof, file-read

I have a list of columns containing text but I just to fetch first upper row from this list. How to do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fr;
  char c;
  fr = fopen("prog.txt", "r");
  while( c != EOF)
  {
    c = fgetc(fr); /* read from file*/
    printf("%c",c); /*  display on screen*/
  }
  fclose(fr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: check out `man 3 getline`. Maybe it is what you want

Comment: `while ((c = fgetc(fr)) != EOF)` would be a start — probably `while ((c = fgetc(fr)) != EOF && c != '\n')` would be what you're after, but it isn't quite clear what you mean.  Or use `fscanf()` to read the 'column'.  Don't forget to check that the file was opened successfully.

Comment: It is not giving me first row. I want first row.

Comment: And `c` should be `int`, not `char`, to handle `EOF` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stop condition is `EOF`, everything will be read to the end of the file, what you need is to read till newline character is found, furthermore `EOF` (`-1`) should be compared with `int` type.

You'll need something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fr;
  int c;

  if(!(fr = fopen("prog.txt", "r"))){ //check file opening
    perror("File error");
    return EXIT_FAILURE; 
  }

  while ((c = fgetc(fr)) != EOF && c != '\n')
  {
    printf("%c",c); /*  display on screen*/
  }
  fclose(fr);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is respecting your code reading the line `char` by `char`, you also have the library functions that allow you to read whole line, like `fgets()` for a portable piece of code, [or `getline()` if you are not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27381998/6865932), alternatively [download a portable version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067149/6865932), and, of course you can make your own like [this one](https://gist.github.com/mrkline/99630570e839a4af0e3b) or [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwicsJPT3qbpAhXYC2MBHb8nC3gQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.w3.org%2Flibwww%2FLibrary%2Fsrc%2Fvms%2Fgetline.c&usg=AOvVaw14nrIkh9p-zzj4rHbFpO8p).

Answer (score 2):

just replace EOF as '\n'(new line char). Than your code will read until reaching the new line. Here is what it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fr;
  char c = ' ';
  fr = fopen("prog.txt", "r");
  while(c != EOF && c != '\n')
  {
    c = fgetc(fr); /* read from file*/
    if(c != EOF){
          printf("%c",c); /*  display on screen*/
    }
  }
  fclose(fr);
  return 0;
}
```

I have not tested it yet but probably work. Please let me know if there is some problem with the code i will edit it.

Edit1:char c; in line 5 is initialized as ' ' for dealing with UB.

Edit2:adding condition (c != EOF) to while loop in line 7, for not giving reason to infinite loop.

Edit3:adding if statement to line 10 for not printing EOF which can be reason for odd results.

Comment: "code will read until reaching the new line" --> unless an `EOF`  occurs first.  Then this code is an infinite loop.  Consider checking both  and use an `int c`.

Comment: You need to check what was returned by `fgetc()` before printing it because trying to print EOF yields odd results.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ty for your comment. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever it's worth, here's an example that uses [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fr;
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t nread;

  if (!(fr = fopen("prog.txt", "r"))) {
    perror("Unable to open file");
    return 1;
  }
  nread = getline(&line, &len, fr);
  printf("line: %s, nread: %ld\n", line, nread);

  fclose(fr);
  return 0;
}
```

Some notes:

- `getline()` can automatically allocate your read buffer, if you wish.
- `getline()` returns the end of line delimiter.  You can always strip it off, if you don't want it.
- It's *ALWAYS* a good idea to check the status of I/O calls like "fopen()".

Comment: Better to use a certain matching printf specifier of `"%zu"` with `size_t`.  Also suggest a `free(line)`