# Reading from txt file into a struct

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

Trying to read from txt file until a semicolon and will store it into a array inside struct.

```
struct Total
{
    char *Name;
    int *No;
}MyCities;
```

This is my struct made the arrays pointers so i can allocate memory later. Depending on the content of the txt. Each line is a entry for the struct.

```
London;15
Oslo;12
vienna;35
```

Let's say this is the content of txt file, it will read the city name into MyCities.Name and the number after the semicolon into MyCities.No

```
    FILE *fp;
    
    char line;
    

    fp = fopen("City.txt", "r");

    for (line= getc(fp); line!= EOF; line= getc(fp)) //for getting number of lines
    {
        if (line == '\n')
            count++;
    }//this is for counting how many lines in txt

    MyCities.No = malloc( count * sizeof *MyCities.No );
    if (MyCities.No == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    MyCities.Name = malloc( count * sizeof *MyCities.Name );
    if (MyCities.Name == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

So at this point I have no idea how should I proceed.

Comment: `for (line= getc(fp); line!= EOF; line= getc(fp))` is usually written `while( (line = getc(fp)) != EOF)`, but it is very unusual to use the name `line` for a single character.

Comment: Your current code is wrong... you can't store multiple city names like this

Comment: Don't you want an array of structs, i.e. so that one struct is one city?

Comment: Use `fgets` to get a line from the file and then `strtok` to break it up into parts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your struct differently. Remember that an integer is `int`, yet a string is `char *`, i.e. a pointer itself. So you probably need to store an `int No` and a `char* Name` in a struct, and store an array of such structs (it is possible to store separate arrays of numbers [`int*`] and names [`char**`] like you tried but I’d not recommend that).

Now, assuming you went the right way and have a struct `City` with a number and a string fields inside, as you know line count (there are ways to avoid that pass but they are more complicated) you may proceed and allocate an array of `City`, e.g. using `calloc(count, sizeof(City))` (it does the multiplication, and also zero-fills the array).

Now you can read the file again (don’t forget to [rewind](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) or reopen it), line by line. [getdelim](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getdelim) should be suitable to read the first field, and [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) is good for everything else.

Comment: Worth noting, [not everyone has `getdelim` in their arsenal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381903/where-how-to-get-the-getline-function-if-it-is-missing-from-stdio-h).

Comment: ugh, of course... I forgot there is an OS that disregards POSIX even where it is really useful