# creating dynamic array of structures in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

```
struct Total
{
    char Name[40];
    int No[40];

};
struct Total *List = NULL;
```

I have this struct which I want to allocate memory for it dynamically.

```
List =(struct Total*)realloc(List,n*sizeof(struct Total));
```

But whenever I use the notation `List.Name` it gives error saying I should use `->` is there a way to do this without using `->` this ?

Comment: You can also use `(*List).Name` or `List[0].Name`.

Comment: `List` is a pointer to the first element of your allocated `Total` structs, hence you need to use `->` to access members.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `->`. What's wrong with it?

Comment: OT: `List =(struct Total*)realloc(List,n*sizeof(struct Total));`: 1: the `(struct Total*)` cast is useless, just drop it. 2: Be aware that `realloc` is used to _change_  the size of an existing memory region. As you didn't show much of your code,  I can't tell if it's correct in your case.

Comment: I feel I saw this code already. Note well: `char` is not a string but a single character. Is that what you need?

Comment: Here is the previous question, for context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652352/reading-from-txt-file-into-a-struct/64652526

Comment: You never *have* to use `->`, since `a->b` is just syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`.  But `->` is easier to read.  Similarly for the `[]` operator:  `a[b]` is syntactic sugar for `*(a + b)`, but again, `[]` is easier to read (provided it's not abused by placing the pointer in the brackets and the offset outside of them).