# I am trying to use getline() to read a file but I keep getting LNK 2019 and LNK 1120 errors

Tags: c, getline

I have to use getline() to read a file for a class and just cant get this figured out. Right now I'm just trying to loop through the file to determine how big my dynamic array needs to be. The file I'm trying to read is in the same folder as the .c file so I don't think its a opening issue but I really have no idea. Thanks in advance.

```
int SCAN(FILE *(*stream)) {
    int size = 0;
    char* buffer = NULL;
    FILE* data = fopen("./hw4.data", "r");
    while (1) {
        getline(&buffer, 32, data);
        if (feof(data)) break;
        size++;
    }
    
    printf("done");
    // Free the allocated line buffer and close the file
    //free(line_buf);
    //line_buf = NULL;
    fclose(data);

    return size;
}
```

Here's the error:

[image: Errors]

Comment: Please show us the errors.

Comment: **getline** is not a standard function. Do you have an implementation?

Comment: I am including both stdio.h and stdlib.h

Comment: **getline** is not in the C lib, you have to write it or find an implementation.

Comment: Use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Zakk I can't use fgets() because using getline() is required in the assignment. 

CGi03 I don't know what you mean, getline() is included in the stdio.h library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381903/where-how-to-get-the-getline-function-if-it-is-missing-from-stdio-h

Comment: FWIW your program has a lot of problems besides just this link error. You should probably turn on some compiler warning flags and take a closer look at pretty much all of this...

Comment: I found my old linux laptop and I tried to compile on there but now getline() segfaults. Any ideas why?