# Error while running "make install" for libiconv: no such file or directory

Tags: makefile, mingw, iconv, msys

Halo,
I tried to install **libiconv** with this tutorial http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw_how_to.html#libiconv.
I installed **MinGW** from heise.de, containing **MSYS**.
In MSYS I made the steps *./configure* and *make*.
Step *make install* finishes with an error:

```
libtool:install: /bin/install -c -m 644 .libs/../bin/libiconv-2.dll /usr/local/lib/../bin/libiconv-2.dll    
/bin/install: cannot stat .libs/../bin/libiconv-2.dll: No such file or directory
make install error
Leaving directory c/libiconv-1.14/lib
```

To solve this problem, I copied **libiconv-2.dll** from *C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin* to *C:\libiconv-1.14\bin*. It was proposed in https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/troubleshooting-configure-make-and-make-install-tutorial/ in section **make install problems**.

> The package you just compiled doesn’t have the install target. In this
>   case you will have to copy the compiled binaries to a bin directory
>   yourself.

As I compiled with **MSYS**, I had the binaries under *C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\local\bin*.

The path to **libiconv-2.dll**   -  *.libs/../bin/libiconv-2.dll*   -   is right, if current directory is *c/libiconv-1.14/lib*.

Does anyone know why **libiconv-2.dll** can't be found? Everything seems to be ok.

**update:** I don't try to install libiconv anymore!!!

Comment: Try running `./configure --prefix=/mingw` instead of just `./configure`

Comment: @user3419537 I runned `make clean`, `./configure --prefix=/mingw` and `make`. Now `make` gives the error `.libs/relocatable.o: In function find_shared_library_fullname: /c/libiconv-1.14/libcharset/lib/./relocatable.c:362: undefined reference to _getline`

Comment: This answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112784/undefined-reference-to-getline-in-c) says that, `#define _GNU_SOURCE` shall be done, if there are problems with getline. I looked in relocatable.c and it contains  `#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
        # define _GNU_SOURCE 1          #endif`.

Comment: It seems that this is a new error. `./configure, make` produces the same "undefined reference to _getline" error.

Comment: This could be deserving of an answer, __if__ you [edit] the question to improve it. At the very least, you need to specify the __complete and exact__ sequence commands you've executed, to get to the error message you show. Without that, I can't offer a worthwhile answer; with it, I surely could.

Comment: I guess the problem with relying on arbitrary internet sources is that you just cannot have any confidence in their accuracy. WRT libiconv and MSYS, your http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw_how_to.html#libiconv reference is one of the __worst__ I've ever seen; it is just __completely wrong__, in every step of the procedure.

Comment: Yet another arbitrary internet source: your https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/troubleshooting-configure-make-and-make-install-tutorial/ reference is actually not bad, but the paragraph you quote from it is __completely irrelevant__ in this case; `libiconv` __does__ have an `install` target, (and an `install-strip` target), specified in its generated makefiles.