# In C, how to print out a txt file line by line?

Tags: c, file, text, fopen

```
int main()
{
   FILE *infile;
   FILE *infile2;
   char input[255],input2[255];
   int status1, status2;

   infile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   infile2 = fopen("test2.txt", "r");
   if(infile == NULL)
   {
      printf("Can not open file 1!\n");
   }
   else if(infile2 == NULL)
   {
      printf("Can not open file 2!\n");
   }
   else
   {
      do
      {
        status1 = fscanf(infile, "%s", &input);
        status2 = fscanf(infile2, "%s", &input2);

        printf("File 1: %s\n File 2: %s\n", input, input2);
     }while(status1 != -1 || status2 != -1);
   }
   fclose(infile);
   fclose(infile2);

   return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ivEj.png)

I would like to print out file 1 in one line not word by word. The same goes for file2. I'm kinda new to C so I'm stuck.

Comment: Use `while (fgets(input, sizeof input, infile)) {...}`

Comment: Your code is very error-prone. What happens if the first file is shorter/longer than the second file? You use `scanf` anyway since you go inside the `while` loop if *either* `status1` **or** `status2` are not -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to read the entire line, use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) function instead of `fscanf`:

```
char *status1, *status2;
   .
   .
   .
do {
    status1 = fgets(input, sizeof(input), infile);
    status2 = fgets(input2, sizeof(input2), infile2);
    printf("File 1: %s File 2: %s", input, input2);
} while (status1 || status2);
```

Note how `printf` no longer uses `\n`. This is because `fgets` keeps `\n` from the file inside your input string.

Comment: Note that `status1` and `status2` are now `char *` and not `int` variables.  It would also be good to check the values of `status` and `status2` before calling `printf()`  If either returns `NULL`, `printf()` will display the results of the previous loop iteration for the corresponding input file.  And what happens if a line is longer than `sizeof(input)`?

Comment: You also do not need the !=NULL check. Boolean expressions are not first class citizens in C. Thus Null means false in C.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou - Thanks for catching that. I missed the NULL check the first edit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was thinking of editing it, but then I thought maybe the writer and editor might not want to since it's not always known that null means false and !null is true to some people and it would be a simpler answer for some future readers, including the person that wrote the question who (by his own statement) is a noob in C :)

Comment: This print each line two times.

Comment: @EsmaeelE It prints each line once, but since there are two files, it may appear that each line is printed twice when the files are identical.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, No I check it twice but if text file, (`file.txt`) just only one line (hello) this print it twice: https://imgur.com/GrSxe0N, And I dont know why.

Answer (score 3):

I made the changes to the code and it works, but another question. If i wanted to compare the files and write out the differnce to a new file like this:

1. File1: My name is Knut
2. File2: My name is KnutAndre
3. File3: Andre (This is the differnce between the files).

My teacher told me to use strcmp and then get the output into a new file, but i dont quite understand him.. Does anyone have some tips that i could try out?

This is how my code look so far:

```
int main()
{

FILE *infile;
FILE *infile2;
FILE *outfile3;
char input[255],input2[255];
char status1, status2;



infile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
infile2 = fopen("test2.txt", "r");

if(infile == NULL)
{
    printf("Can not open file 1!\n");
}
else if(infile2 == NULL)
{
    printf("Can not open file 2!\n");
}
else
{
    do
    {
        status1 = fgets(input, sizeof(input), infile);
        status2 = fgets(input2, sizeof(input2), infile2);

        if(status1 != 0){

        printf("File 1: %s\n\nFile 2: %s\n\n", input, input2);

        int result = strcmp(input, input2);
        printf("\nResult = %d\n\n", result);

        }


    }
    while(status1 || status2);

}
fclose(infile);
fclose(infile2);

return 0;



}
```

Comment: A different question means opening a different question my friend. This is not a forum. This is a Q&A site. You ask something meaningful, people answer, if you have another question, you ask again. Unless your question is of bad quality, etc

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `fscanf` it will only read the characters until the non white space character occurs. When you need to get the input as whole line then you have to use `fgets()`.

From the `man` page of `fgets()`.

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>          EOF  or  a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character
>          in the buffer.

So you have to use like this.

```
  fgets(input,255,infile);
  fgets(input2,255,infile2);
```

While checking condition,

```
while(input != NULL || input2 != NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my school, we make a get_next_line function, who takes a file descriptor and a pointer to a string in parameter.

you can take a look here : https://github.com/juschaef/libtowel/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get+next+line

Comment: There's also the POSIX `getline()` function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112784/undefined-reference-to-getline-in-c for an example.