# Parse getline into buffer by delimeter?

Tags: c, getline

I have a really dumb question that I'm not able to get past.

The goal is to take in a string given by a user, and split it up by spaces and then putting that into an array.

This is my current code so far

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 256
#define PROMPT "myShell >> "
#define PROMPTSIZE sizeof(PROMPT)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    //execvp() to locate executable

    char *buffer;
    size_t bufferSize = BUFFERSIZE;
    size_t inputSize;

    char *tokens;
    char myargv[BUFFERSIZE];

    buffer = (char *) malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(char));
    tokens = (char *) malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(char));


    while (1) {
        printf(PROMPT);
        inputSize = (size_t) getline(&buffer, &bufferSize, stdin);
        if (inputSize == 18446744073709551615) {
            break;
        }

        int i = 0;
        tokens = strtok(buffer, " ");
        while (tokens != NULL) {
            myargv[i] = (char) tokens;
            printf("%c\n", myargv[i]);
            tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i = i + 1;
        }


    }

}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the warning,

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
>   [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
>                myargv[i] = (char) tokens;

Not really sure exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you want a `char *myargv[BUFFERSIZE];`.

Comment: I suspect you would exhaust your memory long before `inputSize == 18446744073709551615`. Note `getline` returns type `ssize_t` not `size_t` for this purpose.

Comment: @Swordfish that just gave me a coredump.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's just to see if Ctrl+D was pressed

Comment: Sure, the simple and proper test is to make `inputSize` type `ssize_t` and then compare against `-1`.

Comment: 1. `sizeof(char)` is always 1. 2. Why do you inconsistently declare `myargv` as a static array, but `buffer` of exactly the same size as purpose - as a dynamic array? 3. The memory allocated for `tokens` is never use at all.

Comment: @getlineHelp if you don't change `myargv[i] = (char) tokens; printf("%c\n", myargv[i]);` accordingly to `myargv[i] = tokens; printf("%s\n", myargv[i]);`, yes, it will.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`getline' in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112784/undefined-reference-to-getline-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

While it is not 100% clear what all you are trying to accomplish with your code, your use of the multiple pointers is a bit awkward.

The first thing that should be sounding ALARM BELLS for you is your need to explicitly cast to `(char)`. If you ever find yourself trying to cast to get around compiler warnings or error -- STOP -- you are doing something wrong.

If your goal is to provide up to `BUFFERSIZE` arguments to `execvp` (or the like), then you simply need to declare `myargv` as an *array of pointers to char*, e.g.

```
    char *myargv[BUFFERSIZE] = {NULL};  /* array of pointers - init NULL */
```

Each of the pointers returned by `strtok` can be used as the argument array for `execvp` and if you initialize the array to all `NULL` pointers and fill no more than `BUFFERSIZE - 1`, you ensure you always provide an array of arguments to `execvp` and provide the required sentinel `NULL` after the final argument.

You can declare your delimiters for `strtok` any way you like, but since you are properly defining constants with `#define`, there is no reason not to add a constant for your `strtok` delimiters as well, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 256
#define PROMPT "myShell >> "
#define DELIM " \n"
```

If you are not using `argc` or `argv` in your code, then the proper declaration for `main()` is:

```
int main (void) {
```

(see: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/))

If you are only reading the line and tokenizing the line to use with `execvp`, then *declaring and initializing* your variables *within the loop scope* ensures they are properly re-initialized each iteration, e.g.

```
    while (1) {
        size_t ndx = 0,             /* line index */
            n = 0;                  /* line alloc size (0, getline decides) */
        ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* return (chars read by getline) */
        char *line = NULL,          /* buffer to read each line */
            *myargv[BUFFERSIZE] = {NULL};  /* array of pointers - init NULL */
```

By declaring your `inputSize`, my `nchr` above as `ssize_t` (the proper return type for POSIX `getline`), you can simplify your test for `EOF`, e.g.

```
        fputs (PROMPT, stdout);
        if ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) == -1) {
            putchar ('\n');         /* tidy up with newline */
            break;
        }
```

All that remains is tokenizing `line` and assigning the pointers to `myargv` at the proper index (`ndx`). You can use a `while` loop, but a `for` provides a convenient way to tokenize with `strtok`, e.g.

```
        for (char *p = strtok (line, DELIM); p; p = strtok (NULL, DELIM)) {
            myargv[ndx] = p;    /* points within line, duplicate as req'd */
            printf ("token: %s\n", myargv[ndx++]);
            if (ndx == BUFFERSIZE - 1)  /* preserve sentinel NULL */
                break;
        }
        /* call to execvp, etc. here */
```

(**Note:** by simply assigning the pointer to token to `myargv[ndx]`, `myargv[ndx]` points to the location of the string within `line`. You must make use of the pointers while `line` remains in scope. Otherwise, you need to allocate memory for each token, assign the starting address for the new block of memory to `myargv[ndx]` and copy the token to the new block of memory. (either `malloc` and `strcpy`, or `strdup` if you have it))

Lastly, do not forget, `getline` allocates, so do not forget to `free()` the memory allocated when you are done with it, e.g.

```
        free (line);    /* don't forget to free memory allocated by getline */
    }
```

Putting it altogether, you could handle tokenizing your line with something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 256
#define PROMPT "myShell >> "
#define DELIM " \n"

int main (void) {

    while (1) {
        size_t ndx = 0,             /* line index */
            n = 0;                  /* line alloc size (0, getline decides) */
        ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* return (chars read by getline) */
        char *line = NULL,          /* buffer to read each line */
            *myargv[BUFFERSIZE] = {NULL};  /* array of pointers - init NULL */

        fputs (PROMPT, stdout);
        if ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) == -1) {
            putchar ('\n');         /* tidy up with newline */
            break;
        }
        for (char *p = strtok (line, DELIM); p; p = strtok (NULL, DELIM)) {
            myargv[ndx] = p;    /* points within line, duplicate as req'd */
            printf ("token: %s\n", myargv[ndx++]);
            if (ndx == BUFFERSIZE - 1)  /* preserve sentinel NULL */
                break;
        }
        /* call to execvp, etc. here */

        free (line);    /* don't forget to free memory allocated by getline */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getlinestrtok
myShell >> my dog has fleas
token: my
token: dog
token: has
token: fleas
myShell >> my cat has none
token: my
token: cat
token: has
token: none
myShell >> happy cat
token: happy
token: cat
myShell >>
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

from [strtok](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html)

> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

the return type is `char *` on the other hand in your assignment

```
myargv[i] = (char) tokens;
```

you are doing a `typecast` of `char *` to `char` I'm sure that's not what you want to do

may be something line this

change `myargv` to hold array of tokens

```
char myargv[MAX_TOKENS][BUFFERSIZE];
```

and in `while` loop instead of assignment `myargv[i] = (char) tokens` use `strcpy`

```
        strcpy(myargv[i], tokens);
        printf("%s\n", myargv[i]);
```

---

let me try and explain why your original program is misbehaving

```
char myargv[BUFFERSIZE];
```

here `myargv` is assigned a memory of `BUFFERSIZE` vitz 256 as in

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+....---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   ..                          255
```

each block is of size `sizeof(char)` or `1 byte`

in `while` loop here

```
myargv[i] = (char) tokens;
```

you got a `char *` which is essentially a `4 byte` number, if you really go to that address and see what is there `byte by byte` you should have seen the first token. however you are now trying to put that `4 byte address` in to `1 byte indexed location` leading to truncation and assignment.

then comes the `printf`

```
printf("%c\n", myargv[i]);
```

now in based on what happened in the previous step, `myargv[i]` now contains a stripped version of an address, which is just a number `"%c\n"` format specifier tries to convert that into the corresponding `ascii` and print giving a garbage.

I'd suggest read somethings on `2d-arrays`, `array of strings`, `char **`

Comment: That's a good point, but when I take away the `(char)` I just get random characters printed back. It works when I added the [MAX_TOKENS] although I'm not super sure why

Comment: not just `MAX_TOKENS` but also you should have changed `%c` to `%s`